# How to do an array of hashmaps?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

This is what I tried to do, but it gives me a warning:

```
HashMap<String, String>[] responseArray = new HashMap[games.size()];
```

> Type safety: The expression of type HashMap[ ] needs unchecked conversion to conform to HashMap[ ]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What gives? It works. Just ignore it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

No, you [cannot](http://google.com/search?q=java+%22cannot+create+a+generic+array%22) parameterize it. I'd however rather use a `List<Map<K, V>>` instead.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

To learn more about collections and maps, have a look at [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using a list of maps. I don't like ignoring warnings. In my experience if you're getting a warning, ur doin' it rong. The only thing I don't understand is why I declare it as a type Map, but when I actually instantiate it I have to use HashMap?

Map<String, String> responseMap;
responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: It's an interface. A blueprint. A contract. Follow the link :)

Comment: Why do would you rather use List of Maps then a HashMap, please explain.

Comment: Java gemerics and arrays mix poorly.  You cannot, for example, create an array of a concrete parametrized type with the `new` operator.  The issue relates to the runtime system being unable to guarantee type safety.  Arrays are covariant and reified.  Generics are invariant and non-reified.  The best solution is to use a List in this case.

Comment: I didnt follow still why generics are allowed in case of ArrayList but not arrays ?

Answer (score 16):

You can use something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class testHashes {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Map<String,String> myMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    myMap1.put("URL", "Val0");
    myMap1.put("CRC", "Vla1");
    myMap1.put("SIZE", "Val2");
    myMap1.put("PROGRESS", "Val3");

    myMap.add(0,myMap1);
    myMap.add(1,myMap1);

    for (Map<String, String> map : myMap) {
        System.out.println(map.get("URL"));
        System.out.println(map.get("CRC"));
        System.out.println(map.get("SIZE"));
        System.out.println(map.get("PROGRESS"));
    }

    //System.out.println(myMap);

}


}
```

Comment: I get Error:(19, 15) java: <identifier> expected

Comment: check your imports and that you are calling put from a method

Answer (score 10):

The Java Language Specification, section 15.10, states:

> An array creation expression creates
>   an object that is a new array whose
>   elements are of the type specified by
>   the PrimitiveType or
>   ClassOrInterfaceType. It is a
>   compile-time error if the
>   ClassOrInterfaceType does not denote a
>   reifiable type (§4.7).

and

> The rules above imply that the element
>   type in an array creation expression
>   cannot be a parameterized type, other
>   than an unbounded wildcard.

The closest you can do is use an unchecked cast, either from the raw type, as you have done, or from an unbounded wildcard:

```
 HashMap<String, String>[] responseArray = (Map<String, String>[]) new HashMap<?,?>[games.size()];
```

Your version is clearly better :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't have an array of a generic type. Use `List` instead.

Comment: Actually, you can *have* an array of a generic type, you just can't *create* one directly. (I don't presume to understand the rationale behind this, but that's what the spec says)

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't want you to make an array of HashMaps, but it will let you make an array of Objects. So, just write up a class declaration as a shell around your HashMap, and make an array of that class. This lets you store some extra data about the HashMaps if you so choose--which can be a benefit, given that you already have a somewhat complex data structure.

What this looks like:

```
private static someClass[] arr = new someClass[someNum];
```

and

```
public class someClass {

private static int dataFoo;
private static int dataBar;
private static HashMap<String, String> yourArray;

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the @alchemist's answer, I added some modifications using only HashMap and ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class ArrayOfHash {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>> myArrayMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    myMap.put("Key1",   "Val0");
    myMap.put("Key2",   "Val1");
    myMap.put("Key3",   "Val2");
    myMap.put("Key4",   "Val3");

    myArrayMap.add(myMap);
    myArrayMap.add(myMap);

    for (int i = 0; i < myArrayMap.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(myArrayMap.get(i).get("Key1") + ","
            + "" + myArrayMap.get(i).get("Key2") + ","
            + "" + myArrayMap.get(i).get("Key3") + ","
            + "" + myArrayMap.get(i).get("Key4"));
        
        System.out.println(); // used as new blank line
    }
}
```