# How can I initialize my generic array?

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist, initialization

I want to have an array of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<MyClass>[] myArray;
```

I want to initialize it by the following code:

```
myArray = new ArrayList<MyClass>[2];
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<MyClass>
```

How can I initialize it?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549192/create-an-array-of-arrayliststring-elements

Comment: I can not have `ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>>`

Comment: When you are on that page , if you hit down arrow you will notice page moving and other answers will appear_magic_ . Having said that choice is more of what you can rather than you want . Any way if you change `new ArrayList<MyClass>[2];` to `new ArrayList[2];` it will work but you will get warning. Not that I am recommending it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not strictly possible in Java and hasn't been since its implementation.

You can work around it like so:

```
ArrayList<MyClass>[] lists = (ArrayList<MyClass>[])new ArrayList[2];
```

This may (really, it should) generate a warning, but there is no other way to get around it. In all honesty, you would be better off to create an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>>(2);
```

The latter is what I would recommend.

Comment: As a rule, though, avoid mixing generics and arrays.  Prefer `List<E>` instead of arrays when dealing with generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HashMap<some key,ArrayList<MyClass>> or ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As arrays are static in nature and resolved in compile time so you cannot do that instead you can use ArrayList. As

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ArrayList<String>[] f = (ArrayList<String>[]) Array.newInstance(ArrayList.class, size);


for(int ix = 0; ix < f.length;ix++)
    f[ix] = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: `Array.newInstance(ArrayList.class, size)` has no advantage over `new ArrayList[size]`. There is never a point in using `Array.newInstance` with a class literal