# How can I convert a generic list to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

I'm beginning to discover the wonders of Java generics...

Apparently, you can't create a generic array:

```
Stuff<Thing>[] array = new Stuff<Thing>[5]; // doesn't compile
```

So obviously, you can't do this either (which works perfectly when generics aren't involved):

```
// thingsList is an ArrayList<Stuff<Thing>>
Stuff<Thing>[] array = thingsList.toArray(new Stuff<Thing>[0]);
```

So my question is, how can I get around this? How can I easily convert a generic list to an array?

Comment: What is `thingsList`?

Comment: Try going through this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863, you might get your answer.

Comment: @RohitJain An `ArrayList<Thing>`

Comment: Why would you expect an `ArrayList<Thing>` to convert to `Stuff<Thing>[]`, and not `Thing[]`? That would certainly not work.

Comment: @RohitJain I meant ArrayList<Stuff<Thing>>

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413571/java-2d-array-of-arraylists/18413894#18413894); one possibility is to define a non-generic type that behaves the same as `Stuff<Thing>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Stuff<Thing>> thingsList = new ArrayList<Stuff<Thing>>();
Stuff<Thing>[] array = (Stuff<Thing>[] )thingsList.toArray(new Stuff[0]);
```

Comment: Actually, Object solution would throw an exception. Updated.

Comment: I once had someone suggest using `<?>`, i.e. `new Stuff<?>[0]` in your example.  I don't know whether that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

It would be the following:

```
Stuff<Thing>[] array = thingsList.toArray(new Stuff<Thing>[thingsList.size()]);
```

However, it is a restriction on Generics that you can't make parametrized arrays, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

So only the following would work:

```
Stuff[] array = thingsList.toArray(new Stuff[thingsList.size()]);
```

But that's a raw type.

Therefore, it's recommended to just use a `List<Stuff<Thing>>` instead rather than an array.