# How to create an array of ArrayLists in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am creating an array but cannot add values to it.

```
ArrayList<SMS>[] lists = (ArrayList<SMS>[])new ArrayList[count];

        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
        {
            String number="",id="";
            number = temp.get(i).addr;
            id = temp.get(i).thread_id;
            lists[i].add(temp.get(i));            // Problem here
        }
```

I am unable to add value to it

Comment: You have to actually create the individual ArrayList objects.  The `new ArrayList[count]` operation only creates the array itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating an array of `null` references, so you need to initialize each of them to a `new ArrayList<SMS>()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<SMS>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int size = 9;
ArrayList<SMS>[] lists = new ArrayList[size];
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<SMS>();
}
```