# Java array of Hashtables

Tags: java, hashtable

I need an array of Hashtables in a program that is storing all words from a given set of documents.

Index 1 of the array holds a hashtable of String -> Double which stores a word, and its count for document 1 (array index 100 = document number 100's hashtable).

I dont need help using this data structure, just in creating it.
I declare the Hashtable Array as follows:

```
Hashtable<String,Double>[] h1 = new Hashtable<String,Double>[];
```

... but this does not compile.

(NOTE: The Double is necessary rather than an Integer in the above declaration for later usage.)

QUESTION:
How do you create an array of hashtables which stores String->Double ???

Any suggestions appreciated guys....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792731/how-to-do-an-array-of-hashmaps

Answer (score 5):

> ... but this does not compile.

That's because the array has no name, `new` expects a number of elements and you can't just allocate an array of [generics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html). Prefer a `List` instead:

```
List<Hashtable<String,Double>> wordCountPerDoc
  = new ArrayList<Hashtable<String,Double>>();
```

Comment: sorry but you can't do this in that way :) if you don't beliebe me try compile it

Answer (score 4):

just use

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Hashtable<String,Double>[] h = (Hashtable<String,Double>[])new Hashtable<?,?>[10];
    h[0] = new Hashtable<String, Double>();
```

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use a `Map<Integer, Map<String, Double> >` ?
this way you don't waste space for non-existing documents, and still get O(1) retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

you can create like this.

```
Hashtable<String,Double>[] arr = new Hashtable[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: you can't declare an array with the parameterized types like that; you have to imply declare it a `new Hashtable[]`.  And you need to give the array a length.

Mixing arrays and Collections, although possible, tends to be confusing and lead to problems in my experience; also HashMap is generally preferred to Hashtable.  So I would tend to prefer a `List<Map<String, Double>>` for this application.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why this is an error are covered in Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ: [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type%3F)

> **Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?**
>
> *No, because it is not type-safe.*
>
> Arrays are covariant, which means that
>   an array of supertype references is a
>   supertype of an array of subtype
>   references.  That is, `Object[]` is a
>   supertype of `String[]` and a string
>   array can be accessed through a
>   reference variable of type `Object[]`.

Arrays and generics can have odd interactions (largely due to implementation compromises to support compatibility). You may be better off (as [larsmans suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449804/java-array-of-hashtables/5449808#5449808)) looking at a suitable collection type such as a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

An array seems to be an unusual choice of structure here. Perhaps you should consider storing your hashtables in a List. It will dynamically resize for you if you don't know how many document you will have ahead of time. If you use an `ArrayList`, you will still have constant-time reads of random indeces (like an array.) I think it's much simpler than using an array, and you still get the generic type checking. If you choose a List, you syntax becomes:

```
List<Map<String,Double>> documentWordCounts = new ArrayList<Map<String,Double>>();
```

Or choose a `LinkedList` depending on what kind of read/write pattern you want.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed size array:

```
Hashtable<String,Double>[] h1 = new Hashtable[]{new Hashtable< String,Double>(),new Hashtable< String,Double>(),new Hashtable< String,Double>()};
```